# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() error

Tags: android, mediastore

I have two devices with the same android version (4.4.2). The problem is that when call a method insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap, "", ""), on one i have error and the other works as planned

> E/MediaStore: Failed to insert image
>                                                java.io.FileNotFoundException: No entry for content://media/external/images/media/3865
>                                                    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:189)
>                                                    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
>                                                    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:939)
>                                                    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:686)
>                                                    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:662)
>                                                    at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:934)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insertImage() can save image if external storage available.